# Helper method to define Vue.js computed properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm using Vue.js with Vuex modules. In almost every module I have an action & mutation called `updateProp` which looks like this:

```
updateProp ({commit}, payload) {
  commit('updateProp', payload)
}
updateProp (state, payload) {
  state[payload.propName] = payload.newVal
}
```

So then when I define some computed property that has a source in the Vuex I write:

```
myComputedValue: {
  get () {
    return this.$store.state.vuexModuleName.propertyName
  },
  set (newValue) {
    this.$store.dispatch('vuexModuleName/updateProp', {propName: 'propertyName', newVal: newValue})
  }
}
```

Very often I have to define multiple computed values like this, so I thought I'll create a global helper method instead:

```
Vue.prototype.$computedDefHelper = (computedPropModel, computedPropName) => {
  return {
    get () {
      return this.$store.state[computedPropModel][computedPropName]
    },
    set (newVal) {
      this.$store.dispatch(`${computedPropModel}/updateProp`, {propName: computedPropName, newVal: newVal})
    }
  }
}
```

So I'll be able to define these computed values in shorter way:

```
myComputedValue: this.$computedDefHelper('vuexModuleName', 'propertyName')
```

But this doesn't work - I get an error that `$computedDefHelper` is not a function - tried various things like using it like a mixing/plugin/non-arrow function etc. but nothing seem to work - is it even possible?

Any tips will be highly appreciated.

EDIT:

Only way I've managed it to work at the moment is to define it as a helper and import it in every module I want to use it so:

```
import { computedDefHelper } from '@/helpers/globalHelpers'
```

so then I can use it to define computed value:

```
myComputedValue: computedDefHelper('vuexModuleName', 'propertyName')
```

But I would like to avoid importing this and have it already built-in (globally) in every component.

EDIT 2:

I think this might be related with order of triggering / lifecycle Vue.js stuff, since if I console log this method in `created` hook, it looks fine, so probably it's something related that these computed methods object definitions are somehow parsed earlier than this global method is registered ?

EDIT 3:

I've created quickly a simpler version what I want to achieve (not working) at code sandbox to play around with: https://codesandbox.io/s/x3661n317o

Comment: Possibly this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613061/vue-js-making-helper-functions-globally-available-to-single-file-components

Comment: What about using mapGetters? https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html

Comment: @MatheusValenza `mapGetters` will only get the value. I want to set it as well.

Comment: @varit05 thanks but I've seen that thread and tried it but without success - e.g. trying to use it as a mixing throws same error: `TypeError: this.computedDefHelper is not a function`

Comment: @lukaszkups and what about `mapActions`?

Comment: @MatheusValenza I knew you will ask :) mixing `mapGetters` (or `mapState`) with `mapActions` doesn't really make it shorter for me - I've wanted to use it as such one-liner really ;)

Comment: @lukaszkups from your codesandbox, you can't define a computed property inside a component by calling `this`. Check this [post](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/cannot-seem-to-recognize-method-call-from-2-way-computed-property/9777/2): you need to define the function outside the `export default` so you can't call it from the Vue instance (defined in main.js)

Comment: yeah that's why I've asked if it's even possible - would really like to see an elegant way of solving it properly where I won't need to import  or define it inside every component :|

Comment: the only alternative now I see is to add it to `window` object to make it reusable? Not really an elegant solution imho :/

Answer (score 2):

You can define a mixin method in your globalHelpers.js, for example `updater`:

```
const computedDefHelper = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    Vue.mixin({
      methods: {
        updater: function(name, payload) {
          return this.$store.dispatch(`${name}/updateProp`, payload);
        }
      }
    });
  }
};
export default computedDefHelper;
```

Then import it in your main.js:

```
import computedDefHelper from '@/helpers/globalHelpers';
Vue.use(computedDefHelper);
```

You can now use it in every components like this:

```
this.updater('vuexModuleName', payload)
```

where `payload` can be reworked according to what you want as parameter.

Comment: thanks, tried it already to return `get` and `set` as a result for computed properties, but still receives `TypeError: this.computedDefHelper is not a function`.

Comment: @lukaszkups `computedDefHelper` is the name of the plugin you import. Use the mixin method name inside the component (in my example it's `updater` but you can call any name you want)

Comment: yes I'm aware of that - I've renamed it to `computedDefHelper` for my case ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create a plugin for this and install this helper property with the Vue instance like this:

```
  import computedDefHelper from '@/helpers/globalHelpers'

  const Plugin = {

    install: (myVue, options) => {
      const aVue = myVue;
      aVue.prototype.$computedDefHelper = computedDefHelper;
    },
  };

  export default Plugin;
```

and in your main.js file like this:

```
Vue.use(Plugin);
```

Comment: still receives `TypeError: this.$computedValueHelper is not a function` when assigning it to the computed property - although if I console log it (`this.$computedDefHelper('modelName', 'propName')`) in `created` hook it looks fine.